# In Android Studio, cannot invoke Activity B from Activity A more than once

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-studio

Further to my previous post, I now want to invoke a child activity from the main activity *a number of times*. In my real project (as opposed to the noddy test below), when the child activity is invoked, its header displays, "Enter first data set" then invites the user to enter some data. This data is actually stored in a common class rather than being returned to the main activity. Then the child needs to be called again with a new prompt "Enter second data set", and the same thing happens.
What I cannot work out is how to do this. If I include two calls to the child, every time, only the second call appears to happen, the prompt appearing in the child activity being "Enter second data set" every time. This startActivityForResult() method is I believe, designed to be used when you want to call an activity and wait for the result (which you do with an onActivityResult() do you not), but it does not wait.

How on earth do I do this? Sample code follows.

Thank you to anyone who can clearly explain where I'm going wrong and what the right code should be.

**MainActivity code extract**

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    TextView maintop = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.maintop);
    maintop.setText(Common.mess1);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button mainbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mainbutton);

    mainbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Child.class);
            intent1.putExtra("Prompt", "Enter first data set");
            startActivityForResult(intent1,1);
            onActivityResult(1,1,intent1);
        }

    });

    mainbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Child.class);
            intent2.putExtra("Prompt", "Enter second data set");
            startActivityForResult(intent2,1);
            onActivityResult(1,1,intent2);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one click listener in the button, so when you call set for the 2nd time it replaces the listener.
What you need to do is set the click listener for the enter first data, don't call to onActivityResult(1,1,intent1) that's not how you do it, you need  override the method, and in  onActivityResult call the 2nd.
Something like this:

```
static final int FIRST_INTENT = 1;
static final int SECOND_INTENT = 2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Button mainbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mainbutton);

mainbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Child.class);
        intent1.putExtra("Prompt", "Enter first data set");
        startActivityForResult(intent1,FIRST_INTENT);
    }

});
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == FIRST_INTENT) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Child.class);
            intent2.putExtra("Prompt", "Enter second data set");
            startActivityForResult(intent2,SECOND_INTENT);
        }
    }
}
```

And in your child activity

```
//DO SOMETHING
....
setResult(RESULT_OK)
finish();
}
```

For more check 
[http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/intents/result.html]
[http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int%29]

Comment: That's brilliant, isma31. Your solution worked first time (except that I had to change "FIRST_INTENT" and "SECOND_INTENT" to "1 and 2 respectively).
Now, in reality, I want to be able to do this 2 or 3 times. I've tried adding another @Override protected void etc. but can't get it to work, as the system tells me it's already defined. So what's the general solution to doing this 3 times or even more? (e.g. "Enter third data set" etc. etc.)
I would be most grateful if you could give this a few more minutes of your time. Thank you.

Comment: @John of York _"So what's the general solution to doing this 3 times or even more?"_  You should use `THIRD_INTENT`, `FORTH_INTENT` etc. Then in `onActivityResult()` check the condition for a proper `requestCode ` and start `Child` with corresponding `Intent`'s extra.

Comment: Thank you both (isma3l and Onik). I've got it now. I've just added "if (requestCode == 22 etc. to the onActivityResult and it seems to be working fine.